# apache proxypass images js css not working

Tags: apache

```
# node --version
v16.20.0
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (IUS)
Server built:   Apr  7 2023 14:49:47
#
```

```
#cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpnodejs.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpnodejs.mydomain.com
    Redirect / https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/
 </VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-1/web
        DirectoryIndex index.php
ServerName phpnodejs.mydomain.com
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/phpnodejs.mydomain.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/phpnodejs.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/phpnodejs.mydomain.com/chain.pem
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
        ProxyPass /index.php !
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+) http://localhost:8000

<Directory "/var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-1/web">
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
        Require valid-user
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-1/web/.htpasswd
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When i hit https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com the images are broken whereas the proxy pass  https://phpnodejs.mydomain.com/demo/element/index.html (nodejs backend server) works perfectly fine without any issues.

Document root is /var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-1/web/

```
# pwd
/var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-1/web/
# ls -l
total 36
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  315 May 15 18:21 autoload.php
drwxrwxr-x 12 apache apache 4096 Apr 26 18:23 core
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 1507 Mar  8 19:40 example.gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  549 Mar  8 19:40 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache   94 Mar  8 19:40 INSTALL.txt
drwxrwxr-x  4 apache apache   52 Apr 11 20:51 libraries
drwxrwxr-x  5 apache apache   75 Mar  8 19:38 modules
drwxrwxr-x  2 apache apache   24 Mar  8 19:16 profiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 3205 Mar  8 19:16 README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 1706 Apr 27 22:33 robots.txt
drwxrwxr-x  3 apache apache  130 Mar  8 19:40 sites
drwxrwxr-x  4 apache apache   53 Mar  8 19:39 themes
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache  804 Mar  8 19:40 update.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 apache apache 4039 Mar  8 19:40 web.config
#
```

```
172.16.16.45 - drupaladmin [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45339
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/ajax-progress.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/align.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/container-inline.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/clearfix.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/item-list.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/js.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/nowrap.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/position-container.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/fieldgroup.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/details.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/progress.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/reset-appearance.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/resize.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/sticky-header.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/system-status-counter.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/system-status-report-counters.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/system-status-report-general-info.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/tabledrag.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/tablesort.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/tree-child.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/contrib/eu_cookie_compliance/css/eu_cookie_compliance.bare.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/contrib/paragraphs/css/paragraphs.unpublished.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_featured_contents/css/root.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_featured_contents/css/featured-contents.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_articles/css/root.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_articles/css/cardium-articles.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_how_it_works/css/root.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_how_it_works/css/how_it_works.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_card/css/root.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_card/css/card.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/css/slick.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/css/slick-theme.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/css/root.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/css/banner.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_contact_us/css/cardium-contact-us.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_contact_us/css/root.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/base/navigation/navigation.base.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/base/pagination/pagination.base.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/base/footer/footer.base.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/base/form/form.base.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/base/button/button.base.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/base/popup/popup.base.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/base/header/header.base.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/navigation/navigation.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/footer/footer.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/form/form.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/button/button.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/popup/popup.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/get-started/get-started.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/mobile-menu/mobilenav.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/layout/header/header.layout.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/css/components/node.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/dist/css/theme/variables.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /libraries/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/global_css/nice-select.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/theme/footer/footer.theme.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/theme/form/form.theme.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/theme/get-started/get-started.theme.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/theme/theme.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/dist/css/theme/accent.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/dist/css/components/custom-components.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/css/theme/header/header.theme.min.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/dist/css/components/dialog.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/dist/css/base/cardium.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.6.3 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/polyfills/object.assign.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/polyfills/element.matches.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/assets/vendor/once/once.min.js?v=1.0.1 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/assets/vendor/jquery-once/jquery.once.min.js?v=2.2.3 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/drupal.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /libraries/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/jquery.once.bc.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/js/main.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/global_js/jquery.nice-select.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/js/navigation/navigation.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/dist/js/accent.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/assets/vendor/js-cookie/js.cookie.min.js?v=3.0.1 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_how_it_works/js/how_it_works.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/contrib/eu_cookie_compliance/js/eu_cookie_compliance.min.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/js/slick.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/js/banner.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/js/header/header.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/drupal.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /libraries/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/misc/jquery.once.bc.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/global_js/jquery.nice-select.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/js/main.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/js/navigation/navigation.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/dist/js/accent.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /core/assets/vendor/js-cookie/js.cookie.min.js?v=3.0.1 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/contrib/eu_cookie_compliance/js/eu_cookie_compliance.min.js?v=9.5.8 HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_how_it_works/js/how_it_works.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/js/slick.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /modules/dac-components/cardium_banner/js/banner.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:28 +0530] "GET /themes/custom/cardium/js/header/header.min.js?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /core/modules/system/css/components/hidden.module.css?rur2ee HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/featured_articles_336_165/public/2023-04/Insurance.jpeg?itok=WYnlggLC HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/zurichlogo_0.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/featured_articles_336_165/public/2023-02/marketplace.jpg?itok=CxhseyjU HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/featured_articles_336_165/public/2023-02/apiimage_1.png?itok=9fy1u_tM HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/2023-01/how-it-works-bg-img2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/2023-04/zurichbanner.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/card_icon/public/2023-04/Launch.png?itok=PfxSLyjv HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/card_icon/public/2023-04/search.png?itok=RNj7_X1C HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/how_it_works_icon/public/2023-01/register.png?itok=zBt73vBw HTTP/1.1" 404 9
172.16.16.45 - - [05/Jul/2023:19:30:29 +0530] "GET /sites/default/files/styles/how_it_works_icon/public/2023-01/search.png?itok=r1sP5QRK HTTP/1.1" 404 9
```

Do i need to add rewrite rule or any apache httpd directive to render the sites, core, themes, modules and libraries folder content located in /var/www/html/phpcode/cardium-version-1/web document root?

Please suggest and guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Kaushal

Comment: Checking in again if someone can pitch in for my earlier post. Thanks in advance

Comment: Checking in again if someone can pitch in for my earlier post. Thanks in advance – 
Kaushal

Comment: I need help with my ongoing issue. Can someone please pitch in? Thanks in Advance